# Replicate list items n times in a F# sequence

Tags: f#, seq

I have a sequence in F#:

```
let n = 2

let seq1 = {
    yield "a"
    yield "b"
    yield "c"
}
```

I want to print every item in the sequence n times. I can do it this way:

```
let printx line t = 
    for i = 1 to t do
        printfn "%s" line

seq1 |> Seq.iter (fun i -> printx i n)
```

Output of this is:
    a
    a
    b
    b
    c
    c

I think this is not the best solution. How to replicate the items  in the sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function to replicate each element of an input sequence:

```
let replicateAll n s = s |> Seq.collect (fun e -> Seq.init n (fun _ -> e))
```

then

```
seq1 |> replicateAll 2 |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a replicate function:

```
let xs = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
xs |> List.collect (fun x -> List.replicate 3 x)
//val it : int list = [1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 3; 3; 3; 4; 4; 4; 5; 5; 5]
```

And you can do function composition on it, which will get rid of the lambda:

```
let repCol n xs = (List.replicate >> List.collect) n xs
```

Comment: on F# 4.x, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather go with a sequence computation expression.
Looks cleaner:

```
let replicateAll n xs = seq {
  for x in xs do
    for _ in 1..n do
      yield x
}
```